# NodeJS Vs Static HTML

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I've a Java Rest API, and I'd like to implement a browser client.
and I wonder which would be better and what are my trade offs in choosing between

1. Static HTML files with backbone that would connect to the REST api and fill in the data feilds..
2. NodeJS Application that would serve the same static files but load the data into the templates with nodejs modules before displaying them ?

Comment: I think Closers may have misunderstood this question. I believe he's asking about whether to use Node as a front tier in his application, and what the advantages are of doing so. That seems like a valid architecture question to ask here, even if it is worded somewhat vaguely... .

Comment: It's not something that should get asked here however. Asking what's better has a high possibility to end in discussions, something we don't want at SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NodeJS is designed for server side. 
If you got already a Java server side which provides REST API, I recommend you to call directly this API from static HTML files or another client... it will be faster than reload data passing by NodeJS modules.

Comment: Not necessarily. Java can be heavy in terms of coding flexibility for threading and especially for implementing validation, since you usually want the same validation rules both client-side and server-side. For these Node is a great fit for, for example, responding to requests for pages and saving/loading drafts, and passing on more intensive work to the Java API.

Comment: It is enough to build all your front end (SPA applications) as static files that connect with a back end (adding nodejs only add to your complexity). I do recommend to put your static files in an nginx server and manage the communication via the nginx, it will reduce the load on your back end and decouple your back end from your front end.